# Not able to view the particular GitLab merge request in my repository

Tags: gitlab, merge-request

Not able to view the particular GitLab merge request in my repository:

While trying to view my repository’s particular merge request as below mentioned error occurred. I can able to view remaining all the merge requests in that repository, error occurred only try to view the particular merge request alone.

Could you share your suggestions, how to resolve this issue?

**Error details snap:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a server-side error, which means you must [check the logs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/logs.html) (assuming an on-premise GitLab server, instead of `gitlab.com`)

Some bug reports (like [48595](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/48595) or [12065](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/12065)) were fixed in more recent GitLab version, so it also depends on your exact GitLab server version.

Other reports, like [31141](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/31141) suggests a permission issue and needs to be investigated or reported.